# Peer not authenticated exception when connecting SAP Cloud Platform to Office 365 API

Tags: java, outlook, office365, sap-cloud-platform

I'm implementing an SAP Cloud Platform Java application to connect to the Office 365 API (https://outlook.office.com/) using OAuth2 authentication. 
When I running it on Apache Tomcat local server I get the response from the server correctly.
When I run the same code on SAP Cloud Platform I get javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated|
In both cases I get the correct OAuth token.
What am I missing here?
The code I'm using is:

```
private Object getResponseFromAzure(String url, String methodType) {
    AuthenticationResult result = null;
    try {
        result = getAccessTokenFromUserCredentials(); // OAuth2 bearer token
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    String accessToken = result.getAccessToken();
    System.out.println("Access Token is - " + accessToken);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpRequestBase request = null;
    if ("GET".equals(methodType)) {
        request = new HttpGet(url);
    } else if ("POST".equals(methodType)) {
        request = new HttpPost(url);
    }

    request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = client.execute(request);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Have you verified if the certificate chain from Azure is trusted in SCP?

https://uacp2.hana.ondemand.com/viewer/368c481cd6954bdfa5d0435479fd4eaf/Cloud/en-US/77a609451dbd46a58991e685c37350d8.html

Sounds like you need to add the certificate and any intermediate certificates to establish the SSL handshake.

Comment: I have not and I'mnot sure how. In the link you sent it mentions a TLS Outbound Connection Test but I don't see it in the Java Application Monitoring. Where can I find this?
And how can I make the certificate from Azure trusted in SCP?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Destination in SCP. Upload the root and intermediate certificates in the Destination service. This is part of the UI.

Connect from your java application using the destination instead of a direct connection. Example code is available at https://help.sap.com/viewer/cca91383641e40ffbe03bdc78f00f681/Cloud/en-US/e592cf6cbb57101495d3c28507d20f1b.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have some doubts about the destination and the certificates:
1)How do I extract the certificate from the outlook API to upload in the SCP?

Comment: 2)In the destination I made a configuration that I'm not sure is the correct one:
Type: HTTP
URL: https://outlook.office.com/
Proxy Type: Internet
Authentication: OAuth2SAMLBearerAssertion
Audience: https://outlook.office.com/
Client Key: <client secret generated in azure AD registrated app>
Token Service URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize
Token Service User: <client id from azure AD registrated app>
Token Service Password: <client secret generated in azure AD registrated app>
System user: <empty>
Is this configuration correct?